# replaceAll() method using parameter from text file

Tags: java, regex, file

i have a collection of raw text in a table in database, i need to replace some words in this collection using a set of words.
i put all the term to be replace and its substitutes in a text file as below

```
min=admin
lelet=lambat
lemot=lambat
nii=nih
ntu=itu
```

and so on.
i have successfully initiate a variabel of File and Scanner to read the collection of the term and its substitutes.

i loop all the dataset and save the raw text in a string 
in the same loop 
 i loop all the term collection and save its row to a string name 'pattern', and split the pattern into two string named 'term' and 'replacer'
in this loop i initiate a new string which its value is the string from the dataset modified by replaceAll(term,replacer)
end loop for term collection
then i insert the new string to another table in database
end loop for dataset

i do it manualy as below
replaceAll("min","admin")
and its works but its really something to code it manually for almost 2000 terms to be replace it.

anyone ever face this kind of really something..
i really need a help now desperate :(

```
 package sentimenrepo;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.io.*;
    //import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    //import java.util.Map;
    /**
     *
     * @author herman
     */
    public class synonimReplaceV2 extends SwingWorker {
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                 new skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter().setVisible(true);

                  Integer row = 0;
                  File synonimV2 = new File("synV2/catatan_kata_sinonim.txt");
                  String newTweet = "";
                DB db = new DB();
            Connection conn = db.dbConnect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tweet", "root", "");
            try{
              Statement select = conn.createStatement();
              select.executeQuery("select * from synonimtweet");
              ResultSet RS = select.getResultSet();
              Scanner scSynV2 = new Scanner(synonimV2);
              while(RS.next()){
                   row++;

                       String no = RS.getString("no");
                  String tweet = " "+ RS.getString("tweet");
                  String published = RS.getString("published");
                  String label = RS.getString("label");
                  clean2 cleanv2 = new clean2();

                  newTweet = cleanv2.cleanTweet(tweet);
                    try{
                         Statement insert = conn.createStatement();
                         insert.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO synonimtweet_v2(no,tweet,published,label) values('"
                                 +no+"','"+newTweet+"','"+published+"','"+label+"')");
                        String current = skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.txtAreaResult.getText();
                  skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.txtAreaResult.setText(current+"\n"+row+"original : "+tweet+"\n"+newTweet+"\n______________________\n");
                  skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.lblStat.setText(row+" tweet read");
                  skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.txtAreaResult.setCaretPosition(skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.txtAreaResult.getText().length() - 1);

                    }catch(Exception e){
                         skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.lblStat.setText(e.getMessage());

                    }

                 skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.lblStat.setText(e.getMessage());

              }
            }catch(Exception e){
                skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.lblStat.setText(e.getMessage());

            }
           return row;
        }
        class clean2{

            public clean2(){}

            public String cleanTweet(String tweet){
               File synonimV2 = new File("synV2/catatan_kata_sinonim.txt");

                String pattern = "";
              String term = "";
              String replacer = "";
              String newTweet="";
             try{
                Scanner scSynV2 = new Scanner(synonimV2);
                 while(scSynV2.hasNext()){
                  pattern = scSynV2.next();
                  term = pattern.split("=")[0];
                  replacer = pattern.split("=")[1];
                  newTweet = tweet.replace(term, replacer);
                 }
             }catch(Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

                System.out.println(newTweet+"\n"+tweet);
              return newTweet;

            }
        }

    }
```

update

---

ive just realize that the code actually works but only for the first row in database, the second row and so on stand still.  here is i update the newest code i ve build

```
public class synonimReplaceV2 extends SwingWorker {

    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
             new skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter().setVisible(true);

              Integer row = 0;

              String newTweet = "";
            DB db = new DB();
        Connection conn = db.dbConnect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tweet", "root", "");
        try{
          Statement select = conn.createStatement();
          select.executeQuery("select * from synonimtweet limit 2,10");
          ResultSet RS = select.getResultSet();
          FileReader readSyn = new FileReader("synV2/catatan_kata_sinonim.txt");
          BufferedReader buffSyn = new BufferedReader(readSyn);
          while(RS.next()){
               row++;
                   String no = RS.getString("no");
              String tweet = " "+ RS.getString("tweet");
              String published = RS.getString("published");
              String label = RS.getString("label");
              String pattern = "";
             while((pattern=buffSyn.readLine())!=null){
                 String patternTerm = pattern.split("=")[0];
                 String patternSubs = pattern.split("=")[1];
                 tweet = tweet.replaceAll("\\s"+patternTerm, patternSubs);
             }

                try{
                     Statement insert = conn.createStatement();
                     insert.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO synonimtweet_v2(no,tweet,published,label) values('"
                             +no+"','"+tweet+"','"+published+"','"+label+"')");
                    String current = skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.txtAreaResult.getText();
              skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.txtAreaResult.setText(current+"\n"+row+"original : "+tweet+"\n"+newTweet+"\n______________________\n");
              skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.lblStat.setText(row+" tweet read");
              skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.txtAreaResult.setCaretPosition(skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.txtAreaResult.getText().length() - 1);

                }catch(Exception e){
                     skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.lblStat.setText(e.getMessage());
                }


          }
        }catch(Exception e){
            skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.lblStat.setText(e.getMessage());
           // System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        Thread.sleep(100);
       return row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Opening the synonym file and iterating over 2,000 lines for every row in your `ResultSet` is a bit wasteful.

Load your synonyms into an in-memory Map once, keyed by unique misspelt term, then do a lookup on the map for every row in your result set, and replace as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Let us use both solutions to build a single solution for you:

First, you create a HashMap with all your keys:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> getMap() {
        //your version would read from the file
        HashMap<String,String> myMap=new HashMap<String,String>();
        myMap.put("min", "admin");
        myMap.put("lelet", "lambat");
        myMap.put("lemot", "lambat");
        myMap.put("nii", "nih");
        myMap.put("ntu", "itu");
        return(myMap);
    }
```

Second, you create a pattern that contains all the keys in your hashmap:

```
public static String getPattern(HashMap<String,String> mapReplacement) {
        String pattern="";
        for (String s : mapReplacement.keySet()) {
            if (!pattern.isEmpty()) {
                pattern=pattern+"|";
            }
            pattern=pattern+s;
        }        
        return(pattern);
    }
```

Next, you can create a cleanTweet method that uses both structures you created:

```
public static String cleanTweet(String tweet, Pattern pattern,HashMap<String, String> myMap) {
        String newTweet=tweet;
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(newTweet);
        int start=0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String key=matcher.group();
            String replacement=myMap.get(key);
            if (replacement!=null) {
                newTweet=newTweet.replace(key, replacement );
            }            
        }
        return(newTweet);
    }
```

This might require some tweaking to perfect (I onyl tested a few cases), but the point is that you are going to iterate a single time in your keys and then iterate only on your tweets.

I hope it helps.

Comment: its seems the best idea, to get my code well structured. but i actually confused how to call the cleanTweet function

newTweet = this.cleanTweet(tweet,this.getPattern(this.getMap()),this.getMap());

it returns an error where the second parameter should be a pattern not a string..

Comment: My idea is not only to structure well the code (which is always a nice side effect), but also to allow you not to loop on the pattern strings for every tweet. Notice that my code creates the map once and the replacement string once (they could be merged, but I preferred the cleaner version).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try, but it seems to me that you've almost got it - just replace this line:

```
newTweet = tweet.replace(term, replacer);
```

with this:

```
tweet = tweet.replaceAll(term, replacer);
```

As you're not using `newTweet` any more, return `tweet`:

```
return tweet;
```

You should also delete the `newTweet` declaration.

Also, you shouldn't read `Scanner` to read lines. Use `FileReader` instead.

Comment: i have used 
replaceAll(term,replacer) 
berfore but it doesnt work
guess i ll try the FileReader, havent try it before.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not really a useful report. How exactly doesn't it work? Also, the other guys have valid points; I did not read the code too closely.

Answer (score 0):

thanks folks
i ve found the answer why the code is not working,

the txt file containing terms and its substitutes should be initiated each time the program read a row from database.

the code would be like this

```
public class synonimReplaceV2 extends SwingWorker {

    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
             new skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter().setVisible(true);

              Integer row = 0;

              String newTweet = "";
            DB db = new DB();
        Connection conn = db.dbConnect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tweet", "root", "");
        try{
          Statement select = conn.createStatement();
          select.executeQuery("select * from synonimtweet limit 2,10");
          ResultSet RS = select.getResultSet();

          while(RS.next()){
               row++;


          FileReader readSyn = new FileReader("synV2/catatan_kata_sinonim.txt");
          BufferedReader buffSyn = new BufferedReader(readSyn);

                   String no = RS.getString("no");
              String tweet = " "+ RS.getString("tweet");
              String published = RS.getString("published");
              String label = RS.getString("label");
              String pattern = "";
             while((pattern=buffSyn.readLine())!=null){
                 String patternTerm = pattern.split("=")[0];
                 String patternSubs = pattern.split("=")[1];
                 tweet = tweet.replaceAll("\\s"+patternTerm, patternSubs);
             }

                try{
                     Statement insert = conn.createStatement();
                     insert.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO synonimtweet_v2(no,tweet,published,label) values('"
                             +no+"','"+tweet+"','"+published+"','"+label+"')");
                    String current = skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.txtAreaResult.getText();
              skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.txtAreaResult.setText(current+"\n"+row+"original : "+tweet+"\n"+newTweet+"\n______________________\n");
              skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.lblStat.setText(row+" tweet read");
              skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.txtAreaResult.setCaretPosition(skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.txtAreaResult.getText().length() - 1);

                }catch(Exception e){
                     skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.lblStat.setText(e.getMessage());
                }


          }
        }catch(Exception e){
            skripsisentimen.sentimenttwitter.lblStat.setText(e.getMessage());
           // System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        Thread.sleep(100);
       return row;
    }
}
```

but im actually want to apply the code in which rlinden made above, but cant figure it out how to call the cleanTweet function.